# NET.CORE and ASPX 404. Is it possible to host aspx files and bring them in with iframes in net core wwwroot folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-1.1

Fairly new to net core as we are currently migrating from .NET environment. Is there a way to add a folder(or simply drop aspx files into wwwroot of web app) and have it run side by side so url structure doesn't break.

I have even tried to add a folder with a sample file in wwwroot called **test/test.html** and it load fine **BUT** adding an aspx within the same folder and trying to run it returns 404 (**test/file.aspx**) yet the file is physically there?

The compilation and configuration is very standard of a plain project net core 1.1 web app and is enabled to use static files as test.html works, any ideas suggestions?

Comment: A .net core web application does not use `.aspx` files but rather it uses `.cshtml` views.  Can you elaborate on what you are looking for?